# Passing parameters from an outside file to a class

Tags: php, class, object, include

I need to have two files. 
Let's call the file controlling a second one: main.php and let's call the secondary file, the one with my code: second.php

In second.php I have:

```
<?php

class tags{

    var $theuser;
    var $thebarname;
    var $theplace;
    var $thetime;
    var $themail;

    function __construct($theuser,$thebarname,$theplace, $thetime, $themail){
       $this->theuser=$theuser;
       $this->thebarname=$thebarname;
       $this->theplace=$theplace;
       $this->thetime=$thetime;
       $this->themail=$themail;

    }

    function give_tags_theuser(){
       return $this->theuser;
    }
    function give_tags_thebarname(){
       return $this->thebarname;
    }

    function give_tags_theplace(){
       return $this->theplace;
    }

    function give_tags_thetime(){
       return $this->thetime;
    }
    function give_tags_themail(){
       return $this->themail;
    }
}


$tags = new tags("John", "Starbucks", "NY", "4:30", "example@example.com");

$user= $tags->give_tags_theuser();
$barname = $tags->give_tags_thebarname();
$place =  $tags->give_tags_theplace(); 
$time = $tags->give_tags_thetime(); 
$email = $tags->give_tags_themail();

// with the data before I will send an email using phpmailer, but that's another story
?>
```

In main.php I need to pass the variables to the class. Meaning that I will delete:

```
$tags = new tags("John", "Starbucks", "NY", "4:30", "example@example.com");
```

from second.php and I will be passing this data from main.php

What do I have to change in second.php and how would main.php be in order to do so?

If I did not explain myself, please tell me so, I'm still a student and I'm probably still messing up with the vocabulary.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using classes then you shouldn't really be doing operations on those classe inside the files that define those classes.

For example given your situation you should define the `tags` class inside a file called `tags.php` then make your `main.php` file the runner of your application, so in that file do:

```
require_once 'tags.php' 
$tags = new tags("John", "Starbucks", "NY", "4:30", "example@example.com");

$user= $tags->give_tags_theuser();
$barname = $tags->give_tags_thebarname();
$place =  $tags->give_tags_theplace(); 
$time = $tags->give_tags_thetime(); 
$email = $tags->give_tags_themail();
```

This is better than writing code which runs your application in multiple files.